# How to simulate longer response time (not timeout) using HttpTest (flurl)

Tags: c#, .net, flurl

I want to configure HttpTest to simulate slow response tests; like wait X seconds before responding with configured `RespondWith*` response.  Any suggestions?

Comment: clarification - I am writing unit tests using flurl - HttpTest.  I see examples of how to setup mock responses; and time out.  I want to simulate a slow response, like I still like to get 200 after waiting 2 seconds or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't directly supported. Unit tests should be fast (`SimulateTimeout` throws a `FlurlHttpTimeoutException` immediately, rather than actually pausing), but I guess I could see this being useful in some kind of integration test.

There is one way you could do this. There's a low-level overload of `RespondWith` that takes a builder func. You could add a pause here, although it doesn't have async support so I'd suggest `Thread.Sleep` over `Task.Delay`. (Not ideal, but honestly it wasn't designed with this use case in mind.)

Something like this in your setup should do it:

```
httpTest.RespondWith(() => {
    // pause for 1 second
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return new StringContent("ok");
});
```

Comment: thx. this shall work; and your comment about some special integration type scenario is exactly what it is going to be used for

Comment: my apology - seems like I spoke too early; I don't see any overload of `RespondWith` that takes a `Func<>`.  I am using flurl.http\2.4.2.  What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry missed your last comment. It's in 3.0 which is in prerelease but stable. Specific enhancement mentioned [here](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/482#issuecomment-564363041).